# @AuraEnabled Support for Apex Class Return Types?

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps

Beginning on page 141 of [The Lightning Components Developer Guide](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/lightning/lightning.pdf), they list the valid types for aura attributes.  Apex Classes and collections are included, so I've written an apex controller method to return a collection of Apex Class objects to later save to an attribute..

But when I write the results of calling my method to the javascript console, I see a single element array and the element has no properties other than __proto__.  I've seen this work correctly with collections of primitives and SObjects.

Are Apex Classes not actually supported as a return type?  I know my @AuraEnabled method is functioning correctly, and my action callback is simply writing the contents of action.getReturnValue() to the console.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

One thing to check is that the accessors on any objects included in the response include the @AuraEnabled annotation. For example, the following tripped me up recently when adapting sample code for a Lightning application:

```
@AuraEnabled
public static List<SelectOption> getPuzzleTypes() {
    List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();

    Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult = Puzzle__c.Type__c.getDescribe();

    List<Schema.PicklistEntry> ple = fieldResult.getPicklistValues();

    for (Schema.PicklistEntry f: ple) {
        options.add(new SelectOption(f.getLabel(), f.getValue()));
    }       
    return options;
}
```

I kept getting empty results, and it was only when I changed the response type that I realized it was a problem with the SelectOption class. This is standard Apex, but it's not Aura-enabled. My own version of it is:

```
public class SelectOption {
    public SelectOption(String value, String label) {
        this.value = value;
        this.label = label;
        this.disabled = false;
        this.escapeItem = false;
    }

    public SelectOption(String value, String label, Boolean isDisabled) {
        this.value = value;
        this.label = label;
        this.disabled = isDisabled;
        this.escapeItem = false;
    }

    @AuraEnabled
    public String label { get;set; }
    @AuraEnabled
    public String value { get;set; }
    @AuraEnabled
    public Boolean disabled { get;set; }
    @AuraEnabled
    public Boolean escapeItem { get;set; }

}
```

I'm not sure if this will help with the issue you're facing, but it might be something you can look into.

Comment: This is exactly the issue. My actual code was returning a collection  of ConnectApi.FollowingPage. I initially thought about returning a wrapper for FollowingPage to simply reduce the payload size. I wish I could accept both yours and Peter's answers though.

Comment: Any possibility on making some of the standard classes such as SelectOption or ConnectApi.FollowingPage be automatically @AuraEnabled? Right now it is much simpler to just use the JSON serialize and deserialize (two LOC).

Comment: Also, I found it helpful to add the class as a controller to my aura component. After this, data began to pull through when I called the method inside of the controller.js instead of the blank arrays I was receiving before.

Answer (score 19):

If you can't get this working, a workaround would be to use JSON to get around the problem, by changing your return type to String and then returning the JSON String of the object.

For example:

If you have in the controller something like:

```
@AuraEnabled
public static MyClass getMyInstanceOfClass() {
     // do stuff
     MyClass myClassInst = getSomehow();
     // do other stuff
     return myClassInst;
}
```

Change it to:

```
@AuraEnabled
public static String getMyInstanceOfClass() {
     // do stuff
     MyClass myClassInst = getSomehow();
     // do other stuff
     return JSON.serialize(myClassInst);
 }
```

Then in your JS:

```
var yourClassObj = JSON.parse( action.getReturnValue() );
```

Comment: This is a working alternative, and as far as I'm concerned the accepted solution until I see an explanation as to why it didn't work out-of-the-box.  Thanks Peter!