# action callback from apex controller a.getReturnValue() is empty

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, custom-object, actionfunction

I have an apex controller that I'm using to run a SOQL query for some data. Initially, I just had the method return the actual Object, but as I'm making reference to many different parts of data, I've created a new Custom Object (inside the controller) to serve as a "ViewModel" so I can initialize field values and navigate the object more directly in the consuming .js code.

APEX Controller Code:

```
public with sharing class FundsRequestCostsController {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static RequestTotals getCosts(Id id) {
        if (id == null) { throw new NullValueNotAllowedException(); }

        FundsRequest__c request =
                [SELECT
                    TotalCost__c,
                    ...
                    Campaign__r.NumberOfOpportunities,
                    ...
                FROM
                        FundsRequest__c
                WHERE Id = :id];
        RequestTotals totals = new RequestTotals();

        totals.TotalCost = (request.TotalCost__c == null) ? 0 : request.TotalCost__c;
        ...
        return totals;
    }

    public class RequestTotals {
        public Integer NumberOfOpportunities;
        public Decimal TotalCost;
        ...
    }

    public class NullValueNotAllowedException extends Exception {}
}
```

Now, when try to access the response object in the .js controller `a.getReturnValue()` returns an empty object.

Before I made the change to introduce the custom `RequestTotals` object, it worked fine (having the `.getCosts()` method return a `FundRequest__c` object)

I've checked `a.getError()` and it contains an empty Array.

Comment: take a look at this post; http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/53596/auraenabled-support-for-apex-class-return-types, you may have to return as string by using JSON.serialize and Parse the string out in your JS controller

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two particular bugs

1.The nested or inner classes always fails for me .I always create a separate class and never mix as inner class if i am using the apex for lightning component

2.Make sure to mark all the properties of the class  as "AuraEnabled"

```
 public class RequestTotals {
    @Auraenabled
    public Integer NumberOfOpportunities;
    @Auraenabled
    public Decimal TotalCost;
    ...
}
```

Comment: The class you need is RequestTotals and not NullValueNotAllowedException

Comment: I'm not able to make the changes you suggest. First, the developer console shows this error when I try to decorate these classes with @AuraEnabled :

**RequestTotals: Types cannot be marked as AuraEnabled**

Second, when I tried to create a new APEX Class for the `NullValueNotAllowedException`, I get this error:

**INVALID_FIELD_FOR_INSERT_UPDATE**
NullValueNotAllowedException: Exception class must extend another Exceptoin class

Comment: You do not need new class for exception throwing and you can create a new class named RequestTotals as I have shown and mark all the properties as @auraenabled .

Comment: Oh, whoops. I didn't pay close enough attention to see that the decoration was on the fields and not the class. Thank you!

Comment: If that answers be sure to mark answered so it helps others

Answer (score 4):

You need to mark the properties of the inner class as `@AuraEnabled` for them to be returned. This is likely why you are seeing a null return value (there is no visible data to return). Note that you may need to make your sets separate instead of inline as that has prevented me from adding the annotation before.