# Displaying Apex REST Callout issue

Tags: lightning-aura-components, rest

I retrieve JSON from an API:

```
public with sharing class BeerRequests {

@AuraEnabled
public static BeerJsonParser getRandomBeer() {
    Http http = new Http();
    HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
    request.setEndpoint('http://prost.herokuapp.com/api/v1/beer/rand');
    request.setMethod('GET');
    HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
    if (response.getStatusCode() == 200) {
        BeerJsonParser suggestedBeer = BeerJsonParser.parse(response.getBody());
        return suggestedBeer;
    }

    return null;
}
```

I parse it to an Apex object using a generated class `BeerJsonParser`

```
//
// Generated by JSON2Apex http://json2apex.herokuapp.com/
//
public with sharing class BeerJsonParser {
    public class Definition {
        public String key;
        public String title;
    }

    public String key;
    public String title;
    public String synonyms;
    public String abv;
    public String srm;
    public String og;
    public List<String> tags;
    public Definition brewery;
    public Definition country;


    public static BeerJsonParser parse(String json) {
        return (BeerJsonParser) System.JSON.deserialize(json, BeerJsonParser.class);
    }
}
```

The JSON is being retrieved (server side) correctly and an Apex object is created as expected.

I want to show this data in my lightning app.

```
<aura:component controller="BeerRequests">
    <aura:attribute name="beerinfo" type="BeerJsonParser" />
    <aura:handler name="init" action="{! c.doInit }" value="{! this }" />

    <ui:outputText value="{! v.beerinfo.title }" />
</aura:component>
```

And use the following init to load the data

```
({
    doInit: function(component, event, helper) {
        var action = component.get("c.getRandomBeer");
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            if (component.isValid() && state === "SUCCESS") {
                component.set("v.beerinfo", response.getReturnValue());
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```

The response in the controller (client side) is valid and state is success. But the `getReturnValue` function (client side) returns an empty object instead of the expected object. This object is **NOT** empty on the server side.

**Question**: Why am I unable to return the `BeerJsonParser` object to my lightning app? I did not create a custom object `BeerJsonParser` in the SalesForce Object Manager.

Comment: By object definition you mean an apex class with field names? No. You can also choose to get the response as a string. the object definition makes it easier for parsing the response received.

Comment: No, by object definition I meant a custom object, created in the SalesForce Object Manager UI. Which defines which fields are available for this object type.

Comment: ``BeerJsonParser `` is not aura enabled

Comment: Thanks abhi for the info, I found this post explaining how to aura enable the object: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/53596/auraenabled-support-for-apex-class-return-types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return object has to be Aura Enabled to be displayed in the a lightning component. All the attributes which has to be made visible need the `@AuraEnabled` annotation, see the question below:

[@AuraEnabled Support for Apex Class Return Types?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/53596/auraenabled-support-for-apex-class-return-types)